# Is it possible to design a C# class that when querying it through reflections will mark itself as positive IsValueType and positive IsClass?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is it possible to design a C# class that when querying it through reflections will mark itself as positive IsValueType and positive IsClass?

Or are they actually mutually exclusive markings?

I know that,

Most primitive types will return (including enums & structs): 
**IsValueType=true, IsClass=false.**

String or any class - abstracts too.. return: 
**IsValueType=false, IsClass=true.**

Interfaces returns: 
**IsValueType=false, IsClass=false**

Comment: What is your use case actually?

Comment: Just building some simple persistence manager for objects to save into some sort of flat files and I want it to include the widest range of types. but regardless I always wondered about it :)

Comment: Just satisfy following requirements: ValueType: `this.IsSubclassOf(RuntimeType.ValueType);`, Class: `(((this.GetAttributeFlagsImpl() & TypeAttributes.Interface) == TypeAttributes.AutoLayout) && !this.IsValueType);
`

Comment: @sll: Is it just me, or is your condition the perfect explanation of why they are mutually exclusive? :)

Comment: @EladLachmi I was going to write that too! :)

Comment: @EladLachmi Indeed, I think he's making a subtle joke. :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'm not 100% on that, but I'll give him the benefit of the doubt, coz it went over my head and not much does :)

Comment: Right, `!this.IsValueType` does the trick :)

Comment: @sll so this means it is not possible to have a type that will be both IsValueType and IsClass never ever..?

Comment: @G.Y It's not possible to have a type that will be both IsValueType and IsClass, see !this.IsValueType line in IsClass implementation in my answer

Comment: @taras.roshko Yeah.. took me some time to digest that - but yes I understand why now.. Thx! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to design a C# class that when querying it through
>   reflections will mark itself as positive IsValueType and positive
>   IsClass?

Let's take a look on these implementations:

```
protected virtual bool IsValueTypeImpl()
{
      return this.IsSubclassOf((Type) RuntimeType.ValueType);
}

public bool IsClass
{
  [__DynamicallyInvokable] get
  {
    if ((this.GetAttributeFlagsImpl() & TypeAttributes.ClassSemanticsMask) == TypeAttributes.NotPublic)
      return !this.IsValueType;
    else
      return false;
  }
}
```

As you can see, `IsValueTypeImpl()` (which is called by `IsValueType` property) **depends on inheritance** AND `IsClass` **depends on** `IsValueType` (!).

Next, [this description of ValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) states that **it's not possible to inherit from ValueType** directly.

So, the answer is **no**, you cannot create type which will be `IsClass` and `IsValueType` at the same time

Comment: That first method is marked as virtual, implying there may be different implementations of this method.

Comment: @BuhBuh can it change? sure, all in all, it's internal framework code, it can change, but i really doubt that public behavior can change, a lot of third party code can depend on it.